# THREE JS, does the type of .ply file make a difference?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I copied the basic `threeJS` [demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=ply#webgl_loader_ply) with a `.ply` file found online that is encoded in `binary_little_endian 1.0` and it worked correctly.

I have since added more `.ply` files but these ones are encoded in `ascii 1.0`, and don't show up/appear (no errors are thrown, the lights and other features of the scene work correctly).

Is it likely that the file encoding has made a difference? Or could these files simply be beyond the line of sight of the camera? (I have tried moving the camera to different places to no avail)

EDIT: Top of the `ASCII` file:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
obj_info Photoneo PLY PointCloud ( Width = 2064; Height = 1544)
element vertex 3186816
property float x
property float y
property float z
element camera 1
property float view_px
property float view_py
property float view_pz
property float x_axisx
property float x_axisy
property float x_axisz
property float y_axisx
property float y_axisy
property float y_axisz
property float z_axisx
property float z_axisy
property float z_axisz
element phoxi_frame_params 1
property uint32 frame_width
property uint32 frame_height
property uint32 frame_index
property float frame_start_time
property float frame_duration
end_header
-0 -0 0
-0 -0 0
...
```

And top of the `binary_little_endian` one:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment File exported by Artec Group 3D Scanning Solutions
comment www.artec-group.com
element vertex 149979
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 300000
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
ª0-B>F†Á€‘|ÂŽ
...
```

Comment: Have you tried to scale down/up the loaded model a bit (similar to the official [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_ply))? In general, `PLYLoader` supports ASCII (`UTF-8`) and binary files.

Comment: @Mugen87 I assume you mean this line `mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.001 );` I've tried it at every power of ten between 0.0001 and 1000 and none worked

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the `PLY` file in this thread?

Comment: I added the tops of the files in the OP

Comment: Can you also share the entire file? I'd like to load it on my computer so I can find out what's going wrong ;)